# Shortcut to switch between add and subtract in weight paint mode?

Tags: shortcut, weight-painting

That is pretty much my question. When I am in weight paint mode, I'd like to use a key shortcut to switch between add and subtract (or cycle with mix but that's less useful in my opinion) blend mode.

Is there a shortcut already? Is there a generic way to setup a shortcut? (a little python won't scare me but I'm not an expert).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could change the brush: There are `Add` and `Subtract` brushes (and more for all blend modes) which will set all options of the selected brush including the blend mode. So you can even configure more settings of the brushes and select them with one shortcut.

The number keys (not on the number pad) are used as shortcuts for the brushes. You can select the `Add` brush with <kbd>1</kbd> and the `Subtract` brush with <kbd>9</kbd>. They are numbered from one to nine in the same ordering as they appear in the brush selection.